# File moving command works on both Unix and Windows

Tags: windows, shell, unix

I need to write a simple command that works on both Unix and Windows that move a file from one directory to another directory(E.g: 2 files with the same name movingfile.sh and moveingfile.bat).
Any help?

Comment: for cross-OS compatibility you should consider python. Or java. Or any language designed for cross-OS compatibility. You cannot write native OS commands and expect them to work for other OS than the one they were designed for.

Comment: one other option here would be to install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows and then you have most of the linux commands emulated on windows.

Comment: I find the question confusing. Are you looking for a solution such that when you give the command `movingfile source dest` on either Windows or Unix, it will do the same thing? (If so, it's probably a better fit for [su].) Or are you looking to write a single program, script or whatever that works on both platforms? Or something else? Either way, please **[edit]** the question to clarify exactly what you want to know.

Comment: It might be possible to build a text file that can function both as a .sh and as a .bat but probably not by making each individual command cross-platform; for a start, the file paths look different.

Answer (score 0):

> For [Unix](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-copy-file-command/),try this:

```
cp source dest
```

> and, for [Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm) do this:

```
copy source dest
```

As, you can see commands are different. So, you cannot create a single call in both OS to do the same for you. But, there are few commands like rmdir, shutdown, sort etc which are common in both OS. See [here](http://www.lemoda.net/windows/windows2unix/windows2unix.html) to look for common commands.